# Abstract class variable with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am using spring and Hibernate and Dao design pattern for the my project, In my `GenericDaoImpl`(Abstract class) class has "tenentId", I want to set the "tenentId" when use login to the System. My other DaoImpl classes extends from `GenericDaoImpl`, so I need to set the tenentId(It's define in `GenericDaoImpl`) user login time and reset the "tenentId" when user log out.

What is the best way to do this?

In my test cases I tried @Autowired the "GenericDaoImpl" but I couldn't do that, It throws an exception telling, `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type`. I know the problem now,

(We can't create instance of abstract classes,if use tenantId as static variable, is it going to be a problem?)
Can any one suggest me any solution?

Thank you,
Udeshika

Answer (score 1):

if you are developing multi-tenancy application and would like to have tenant aware application context then have a look [spring-tenancy](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-tenancy). This will help you to have beans injected which are tenant aware.

if you want to multi-tenancy at hibernate layer then you can also look at [multi-tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) feature of hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for the response, As you said we have implemented multi-tenancy in Hibernate layer, we haven't done it in spring side, now I want to set the tenantId when user log in to the system. tenantId is in GenericDaoImpl(Abstract class),if I assign tenantId when user log in to the system. we can reduce lot of rework, could you suggest me a way to do that?, Thank you again